# Changing a variable from main thread in threaded-function from other module in python

Tags: python, multithreading, shared-memory, sharing

I am trying to use multithreading in python an I would like to access a variable, defined in a main thread inside a function from other module, which is called in a separate thread from the main thread.

worker_module:

```
def function_foo():
   do_some_heavy_computing()
   shared_set.add(value)
```

Main module:

```
from threading import Thread
import worker_module     

shared_set = set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker_thread = Thread(target=worker_module.function_foo,args=())
    worker_thread.start()

    # go on and make some progress without waiting
```

I want to be able, to add some value to the shared set without waiting for *function_foo* to finish. I am unsure how to "share" the set between the two threads and functions in different modules.

Comment: How about pass the `shared_set` to the thread function explicitly? `Thread(target=worker_module.function_foo,args=(shared_set,))` You need to modify the function signature to receive the `shared_set`.

Comment: Oh thanks, you are right. I did not expect to see the changes made by the worker thread in main thread when passing the shared variable as an arguments. I wonder if this is the best way to do it, but it works.